# How do I transfer data from Node.JS to an ExpressJS html?

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm pretty freshly learning JavaScript, Node.JS and HTML. Planning to use ExpressJS to display content as follows:

`var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`

I want to have JSON formatted Data sent to the HTML page and want the user to be able to do requests to an API (that returns more JSON-Formatted Data, yay) and have the results displayed - if possible without reloading the page.

As I said I'm pretty new to this - so any resources or hints would be very appreciated.

On a sidenote, I am trying to stay at NodeJS because I want to access a MySQL database later on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, but here is some information to get you started in the right direction.

1. > Planning to use ExpressJS to display content as follows:
   >   `var app = express();
   >   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`

Okay, but this doesn't explain how you are going to serve content. If you are just using Express to serve static documents, then this will work. It may be worth your time to get started using a view engine such as [EJS](http://ejs.co/) or [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/). EJS is usually easier to learn because there is no special syntax, you just wrap plain javascript in `<% %>` tags. There are a multitude of tutorials on using both of these view engines.

2. > I want to have JSON formatted Data sent to the HTML page

If you are sending static content, you need do nothing more than make a [fetch request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [xhr request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). I recommend getting familiar with fetch first, as it is generally easier to work with than xhr.

With the promise that is returned from that fetch request, you can have some javascript loop through the information and create HTML elements using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore). Using this method will not require a page refresh.

Of course, this is just how you would do it with Vanilla JS, and for something like this, there is no need to go bigger. But eventually it becomes easier to use a library like React to create an SPA.

3. > I want to access a MySQL database later on.

Learning how to render json into a page now will likely simplify this step later on, since the Node Mysql driver returns a plain javascript object as a result of its queries, which can easily be sent to the client using something along the lines of `res.send(JSON.stringify(results)`.

---

There are a multitude of tutorials and github repos on these topics. I recommend doing a little bit of research before diving in, but it all comes down to how much time you spend writing code and debugging.